# Is there an easy way to simulate check behabiour in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to keep data from checkboxes in database.
Is there an easy way to change value of row i to 1 and values of all other rows to 0? Or I have to iterate over all rows?
I also sow such solution:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DragViewSyncTable.COLUMN_PLAYER_PREPARED, 0);
context.getContentResolver().update(DragViewSyncContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, null, null);
values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DragViewSyncTable.COLUMN_PLAYER_PREPARED, 1);
context.getContentResolver().update(DragViewSyncContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, DragViewSyncTable.COLUMN_ID + " =? ", new String[]{""+i});
```

Comment: Use an Update query?

Comment: @Skynet in my example i am using it, but i hope there is something better then  making 2 updates

Comment: Why two updates? Can't use a Where clause?

Comment: @Skynet one `Update` to set whole colume to `0` and second `Update` to set selected rows to `1`

Comment: I think 0 should be pre populated, at the very first nothing is checked right?

Comment: @Skynet it can be checked from begining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the row's primary key (I'll use the rowid), you can run the equivalent to the following query:

```
UPDATE table SET checked = (rowid == ?)
```